# Can Wix Bundle access and call function from a DLL included in within an included MSI?

Tags: windows, dll, wix, windows-installer

I have a solution that includes a WixBundle with 2 internal MSIs.

I would like to share code between the bundle and my product, for example -
I have a project that is calling a function isLegit(), I would like that both my product and the WixBundle to use the same function, without duplicating the code.

I imagine it is somehow possible to pack all the shared functions I need in a single project (DLL), and open it via the bundle, but I can't find anything on how this should be done.

Any guidance appreciated

I did manage to achieve this behavior by using .h files only and include them in both projects. But this is not the correct way to do this I assume...

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly build a single DLL and use that both in your product and bundle's BootstrapperApplication. But the DLL file is duplicated for use in the bundle and the installation package for the product.